# Android ListView get current position in visible items

Tags: android, listview

If the `ListView` only shows 5 items, and the all data is 40 items. How can I get the current selection is which position in visible items (1~5)? I have tried  `getSelectedItemPosition` but it will return the position in all data. I want the position number in visible items shows on each item.

```
    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        @Override 
        public int getCount(){
         ...
        }
        @Override 
        public Object getItem(int position){
         ...
        }
        @Override    
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {  
           // I want to get the position number in visible items here
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Andry please post some code

Comment: Can you try this `listView.getSelectedItemPosition() - listView.getFirstVisiblePosition()` this will return you position between `1-5`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`getFirstVisiblePosition()` can get first visible position in all items,so you can use `getSelectedItemPosition()-getFirstVisiblePosition()` to make it.

Answer (score 1):

`getFirstVisiblePosition()` can get first visible position and `getLastVisiblePosition()` can get last visible position.
So `getLastVisiblePosition()-getFirstVisiblePosition()` returns the number of visible item.